# cmd forfiles print each word file path is not working

Tags: batch-file, pdf, cmd, ms-word

I have a default pdf printer, with right click print i create a pdf of a .doc file.

I try to print all .docs in a folder with a batch file.
The next cmd is working:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\Office16\WINWORD.EXE" myfile.doc /q /n /mFilePrintDefault /mFileExit /mFileCloseOrExit
```

Now i try to use cmd forfiles to print/create pdf's of all files.
But i get en error, it's something wrong with the path for winword.exe:

```
forfiles /m *.doc* /c "cmd /c C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\Office16\WINWORD.EXE @file /q /n /mFilePrintDefault /mFileExit /mFileCloseOrExit "
```

I tried double and triple double quotes but it's not working. Some idea?

Comment: Try this: `forfiles /m *.doc* /c "cmd /c 0x22C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\Office16\WINWORD.EXE0x22 @file /q /n /mFilePrintDefault /mFileExit /mFileCloseOrExit"` (see the added quotes as `0x22`)

Comment: Its not working, Error: 'C:\Program' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file. It's the same error with double, triple double quotes.
....

Comment: The escape character in batch scripts is ^. So use `forfiles /m *.doc* /c "cmd /c ^"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\Office16\WINWORD.EXE^" @file /q /n /mFilePrintDefault /mFileExit /mFileCloseOrExit"`

Comment: Also "" will work. So try `forfiles /m *.doc* /c "cmd /c ""C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\Office16\WINWORD.EXE"" @file /q /n /mFilePrintDefault /mFileExit /mFileCloseOrExit"`

Comment: Okay... try this: `forfiles /m *.doc* /c "0x22C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\Office16\WINWORD.EXE0x22 @file /q /n /mFilePrintDefault /mFileExit /mFileCloseOrExit"` (actually I don't see any reason why to use `cmd /C`)

Comment: forfiles /m *.doc* /c "cmd /c ^"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\Office16\WINWORD.EXE" @file /q /n /mFilePrintDefault /mFileExit /mFileCloseOrExit"
ERROR: Invalid argument/option - 'Files'.

Comment: @ aschipfl this is partialy working, word opens and says: file not found Copy.doc, but there is no Copy.doc file, from where comes the name copy? I think the winword parameters are the problem now. Error: directory name isnn't valid /mFileCloseOrExit.doc.

Comment: @Gerhard, the problem is that `cmd /C` strips quotes, so the path to `winword.exe` is left unquoted; escaping does not help here; but `cmd /C` is not needed to call `winword.exe` at all...

Comment: The `/m...` are there to call macros, so they have to be there...

Comment: Yes i know, but do i have to escape this params?

Comment: Use `/S` with `cmd` and wrap everything in quotes, it will only remove those outer quotes.

Comment: Why are you using `FORFILES`?  You are not using the date functionality of `FORFILES` so you can just use a normal `FOR` command which will simplify your code.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
@echo off
for %%f in (*.doc*) do (
    "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\Office16\WINWORD.EXE" %%f /q /n /mFilePrintDefault /mFileExit /mFileCloseOrExit
    echo %%f
)
```

it will execute `"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\Office16\WINWORD.EXE" [filename] /q /n /mFilePrintDefault /mFileExit /mFileCloseOrExit` for all file in the folder while replacing [filename] with the actual file name